# regarding shuffling the conditions in xsl

Tags: xslt-1.0

I have a query for xsl:when that is I have the below query..

```
<xsl:if test="$IsCC='false'">
<xsl:choose>
<xsl:when test="./EMDefinition and ./EMMRate">
<xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
</xsl:when>
<xsl:whentest="./EMtion and ./EMRate">
<xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
</xsl:when>
</xsl:choose>
</xsl:if>
```

now I want to shuffle it is such that when both the xsl when conditions fails it should print false by default, in xslt 1.0 , folks please update, early response will be much appreciated

Answer (score 0):

you can add an `xsl:otherwise` to produce the false output

```
<xsl:choose>
    <xsl:when test="./EMDefinition and ./EMMRate">
        <xsl:value-of select="'AAA'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:whentest="./EMtion and ./EMRate">
        <xsl:value-of select="'BBB'" />
    </xsl:when>
    <xsl:otherwise>
        <xsl:value-of select="'false'" />
    </xsl:otherwise>
</xsl:choose>
```